# Subjuntivo ou indicativo depois de "desde que" e "talvez"?

Tags: gramática, modo-subjuntivo

Ando a ler o [*Dom Casmurro*](http://machado.mec.gov.br/images/stories/pdf/romance/marm08.pdf) de Machado de Assis (1899), e deparei-me com umas frases curiosas para padrões atuais, pelo menos para os meus:

> Um dos costumes da minha vida foi sempre concordar com a opinião provável do meu interluctor, ***desde que*** a matéria não me ***agrava, aborrece ou impõe***.

Aqui o narrador e protagonista escreve depois de se ter separado de Capitu, a sua apaixonada:

> Outra vez senti os beiços de Capitu. ***Talvez abuso*** um pouco das reminiscências osculares; mas a saudade é isso mesmo; é o passar e repassar das memórias antigas.

Ora eu, e creio que toda a gente hoje, nas frases acima escreveria *agrave, aborreça ou imponha* e *abuse*. Que é que se passa, o uso do subjuntivo é hoje de facto obrigatório nestas situações? As passagens do Machado de Assis parecem indicar que já foi normal usar o indicativo a seguir a *talvez* e *desde que*. Quando é que deixou de o ser? Que outros exemplos mais ou menos recentes há do uso do indicativo em situações semelhantes?

Comment: No primeiro trecho achei confuso o uso do indicativo após "desde que". Mas no segundo, ele poderia estar se referindo a ele mesmo como ele lembra demais dos beijos de Capitu, justificando que a saudade causa isso nele, por isso o Indicativo

Comment: @tdmsoares O narrador, que é o protagonista, está a falar de si mesmo. Agora se isso hoje em dia não justificaria, creio, dizer «talvez abuso». Mas a pergunta é em parte sobre isso.No link da pergunta tens o texto completo.

Comment: Jacinto, com o Acordo Ortográfico entrando em vigor no dia primeiro deste mês, "fato" deixou de ter "c"  (risos)

Comment: Não sei explicar porque o uso, mas vamos lembrar que Machado de Assis é um escritor brasileiro do século XIX, em uma época em que ptPT e ptBR eram mais semelhantes entre si. Se há formas curiosas para ti em Dom Casmurro, para nós brasileiros do século XXI elas são tantas quanto ou mais.

Comment: O "c" de *facto* é pronunciado em Portugal, por isso mantemo-lo. É uma das palavras com dupla ortografia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concordo que essas duas construções não são aceites pela maioria dos falantes europeus, especialmente a primeira. Trocar aí o subjuntivo pelo indicativo altera a interpretação de *desde que* duma conjunção condicional para uma conjunção temporal, como mostram estas duas frases:

> (1) Desde que traga provas, acredito nele.
>   (2) Desde que traz provas, acredito nele.

No caso de um *talvez* preposto ao verbo, eu também rejeitaria frases como as que dás, ou como esta do CETEMPúblico:

> (3) *par=ext1336771-clt-92a-2*: No entanto, se está de passagem, talvez é mais sensato apanhar o autocarro.

No entanto, repara que se *talvez* for posposto, já é obrigatório usar o indicativo:

> (4)  No entanto, se está de passagem, é talvez mais sensato apanhar o autocarro.

Tenho muita dificuldade em encontrar uma diferença semântica entre (3) (com *seja*) e (4).

No Brasil, a regra parece ser a mesma, pelo menos segundo os dois gramáticos citados [nesta dissertação de Tatiana Pimpão](https://repositorio.ufsc.br/bitstream/handle/123456789/112299/181677.pdf) (pág. 16). Mas, contrariando esta norma, a autora mostra que o *talvez* preposto só é acompanhado pelo subjuntivo em 73% das ocorrências num corpus da região sul do Brasil. Sônia dos Santos, [na sua tese](http://www.repositorio.ufba.br:8080/ri/bitstream/ri/11600/1/S%C3%B4nia%20Moreira%20Coutinho%20dos%20Santos.pdf), analisa um corpus de comunidades rurais afro-brasileiras e, das 14 ocorrências com talvez, o subjuntivo só ocorreu em duas.

Já [Epifânio Dias](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/biografias/epdias.html) (1841-1916), na sua [*Syntaxe histórica portuguesa*,](https://books.google.nl/books?id=gcBQAAAAMAAJ&dq=editions%3A5kQQFEEcgxgC) admite ambas as formas:

> O conjunctivo emprega-se independentemente, a par com o indicativo, nas orações de *talvez* e *quiçá* (conjunctivo potencial)
>       *no mundo todo talvez se não ache um paiz onde.. se encontrem tam villans, tam ridiculas, e absurdas construcções públicas como essas quasi todas que ha um século se fazem em Portugal (Garret, Viag., 180). Talvez foi elle | o primeiro cantor que.. | Soube entoar melodioso um hymno (Herc. Pões. 23).*

Portanto a eliminação da hipótese de usar o indicativo com um *talvez* pré-verbal parece ter acontecido na passagem do séc. XIX para o séc XX. Uma pesquisa no [Corpus do Poruguês](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/x.asp) parece suportar esta suspeita. Só começa a haver ocorrências para `talvez [VS*]/[VT*]` (*talvez* seguido de presente ou imperfeito do subjuntivo) no séc. XIX (com um número de ocorrências por total de palavras semelhante à do séc. XX). Já para o indicativo (`talvez [VP*]/[VJ*]/[VK*]`, i.e., talvez seguido do presente, perfeito ou imperfeito do indicativo), temos ocorrências a partir do séc XVII, com um pico no séc XIX e queda acentuada no séc XX. Contudo, o número de ocorrências é reduzido e grande parte são falsos positivos.

Sobre *desde que* não encontrei muita coisa, e dado que a conjunção pode ter dois significados distintos, não será tarefa fácil contar ocorrências em *corpora*. Ana Neta, em [*O uso de formas do indicativo por formas do subjuntivo no português brasileiro*](http://gel.locaweb.com.br/estudoslinguisticos/edicoesanteriores/4publica-estudos-2006/sistema06/752.pdf) mostra que *desde que* só seleciona o subjuntivo em duas de 10 ocorrências na fala da região Norte-Mineira. Esta [tese de doutoramento de Erica Almeida](http://www.letras.ufrj.br/posverna/doutorado/AlmeidaES.pdf) indica a ocorrência do indicativo/subjuntivo ao longo dos séculos com vários conectores concessivos, mas não com *desde que*.

Comment: Excelente. Não queres traduzir aqueles [VS*]/[VT*] etc. em português corrente. Tornava a leitura mais fácil. O que é curioso é que eu não me lembro de encontrar estas coisas noutros autores do século XIX.

Comment: @Jacinto Feito.

Comment: A sensible discussion.  +1