# Como é que «una» e «unus» do latim deram em «uma» e «um» no português?

Tags: etimologia, fonologia

[***Uma***](http://www.aulete.com.br/uma) vem do latim [***una***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/una#Latin), tal como [***um***](http://www.aulete.com.br/um) vem de [***unus***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unus). Ora estas palavras latinas deram no italiano, catalão, castelhano, etc. [***una***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/una) e [***uno***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uno). No caso do ***um*** consigo pelo menos especular uma via, possivelmente errada (ver comentários abaixo): perdemos a vogal final, o som ***/n/*** deu lugar à nasalização da vogal anterior, como aconteceu geralmente em fim de sílaba; e depois foi uma mera convenção gráfica que ditou indicarmos com ***m*** a nasalização duma vogal no fim duma palavra. Imagino que no francês um processo fonético parecido tenha transformado o ***unus*** em ***un***, só que a convenção gráfica francesa é indicar com ***n*** a nasalização de todas as vogais, mesmo no fim de palavras. Mas no francês ao menos, o latim ***una*** ficou-se por [***une***](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/un/80516?q=une#79549). Mesmo em português, as mesmas palavras latinas ***unus*** e ***una*** deram nos adjetivos ***uno*** e ***una*** (indivisível). Como é que apareceu o som ***/m/*** em ***uma*** é que é mais surpreendente.

Como e quando é que se deu então a transformação de ***unus*** em ***um*** e de ***una*** em ***uma***?

Comment: Se ires da forma castelhana e asturiana (una) à galega (uña) à mirandesa (ũa), acho que será possível notar uma possibilidade de como: os lábios (ao menos para mim), fecham-se e põem-se um pouco mais redondos quando já não tem consoante. Ao fechar-se um pouco mais e pôr-se um pouco mais redondos, a pronúncia fica mais como um M aproximante. Mas só é uma hipótese feita rápida. Pode ser totalmente errada

Comment: Em _um_ não creio que o 1o passo tenho sido o desaparecimento da final vogal, já que se vê _huũ_ e _hũu_ em textos antigos. Quanto a _una_, desde que há textos em português que se vê _hũa_ (muito mais frequente que _una_ no CIPM) e até _huũa_. Daí ao _m_ não sei. Por exemplo _lũa_ passou simplesmente a _lua_.

Comment: @Artefacto Reformulei a pergunta: agora pergunto também como se chegou ao *um*.

Comment: (@guifa, não leves a mal, espero que ajude: "se fores", "quando já não há" ou "quando deixa de haver", "porem-se".)

Comment: @ANeves Admiro pessoas assim: vêm da borga a meio da noite, mas ainda encontram disposição para ajudar os outros, e lucidez para o fazer bem!

Comment: Faz tempo que não entro aqui. Quando entro, me deparo com esta pergunta tão divertida! Há tanto o que dizer sobre esse assunto! Espero que eu consiga arranjar tempo para talhar uma resposta.

Comment: @Bell, força nisso, fico então à espera da tua resposta. O raio desta pergunta está encalhada à quase ano e meio!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O ⟨uno > um⟩ deve-se por [convenção ortográfica](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/por-que-no-portugu%c3%aas-utiliza-m-em-vez-de-n-no-final-da-palavra). Quanto ao ⟨una > uma⟩, eis o motivo:

No galego-português (GL-PT, ou português antigo), palavras latinas paroxítonas e proparoxítonas da forma `/-Vna, -Vno/` (onde `V` é uma vogal qualquer) sofreram uma alteração fonética, na qual o som `/n/` fundiu-se com a primeira vogal criando um hiato nasal-oral. No português moderno (e no galego) esses hiatos transformaram-se em ditongos, monotongos, hiatos orais e até mesmo desaparecendo por inserção de consonante.

Eis a lista dessas alterações (tabela de fusões nasais).

```
    =====EVOLUÇÃO FONÉTICA====  =====EVOLUÇÃO ORTOGRÁFICA=====
##. LATINO > GL-PT > PORTUGUÊS  LATINO    > GL-PT  > PORTUGUÊS

A1. /-a.nõ > -ã.o  > -ãw̃/       ⟨manum    > mão    > mão⟩
A2. /-a.na > -ã.a  > -ãː/       ⟨mattiana > maçãa  > maçã⟩

O1. /-o.nõ > -õ.o  > -õw̃/       ⟨bonum    > bõo    > bom⟩
O2. /-o.na > -õ.a  > -o(w).a/   ⟨corona   > corõa  > coroa⟩

E1. /-e.nõ > -ẽ.o  > -e(j).o/   ⟨frenum   > frẽo   > freio⟩
E2. /-e.na > -ẽ.a  > -e(j).a/   ⟨sirena   > serẽa  > sereia⟩

I1. /-i.nõ > -ĩ.o  > -ĩ.ɲo/     ⟨vinum    > vĩo†   > vinho⟩
I2. /-i.na > -ĩ.a  > -ĩ.ɲa/     ⟨gallina  > galĩa† > galinha⟩

U1. /-u.nõ > -ũ.u  > -ũw̃/       ⟨unum     > (h)ũu† > um⟩
U2. /-u.na > -ũ.a  > -ũ.ma/     ⟨una      > (h)ũa† > uma⟩
```

†Os artigos indefinidos podiam ser escritos com ou sem ⟨h⟩ (tanto ⟨ũu, ũa⟩ quanto ⟨hũu, hũa⟩); e ⟨vĩo⟩ também pode ser encontrado como ⟨vỹo⟩ ou ⟨vinno⟩, dependendo do local, período e autor.

Os casos Ux são interessantes pois são raras as palavras latinas terminadas em ⟨-unum, -una⟩, sendo o numeral/artigo o mais notável, onde tal transformação ocorreu. No galego-português, a palavra *"ũa"* era pronunciada como um hiato nasal; e, no português moderno, transformou-se em duas vogais intercaladas por uma consoante nasal ("*u**m**a*"). Isso não é estranho pois nos casos Is também houve um hiato sendo intercalado por uma consoante: "galĩa > galinha".

Num primeiro estágio, no galego-português, criou-se os hiatos a partir da fusão e eliminação do `/n/` latino que havia entre essas vogais:

- Nos casos Is ocorreu `/i.na > ĩ.a/`.
- Nos casos Us ocorreu `/u.na > ũ.a/`.

Num segundo estágio, ainda no galego-português, estes hiatos foram quebrados pela inserção de uma [aproximante nasal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_approximant) com características fonéticas similares à vogal que inicia o hiato:

- Nos casos Is, a vogal `/i/` ocorre na posição palatal com os lábios abertos. Portanto, a aproximante nasal inserida é a palatal não-labializada `/j̃/`: `/ĩ.a > ĩ.j̃a/`. Uma das grafias de "galinha" deste período refletem a inserção da aproximante: ⟨[galỹa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gal%E1%BB%B9a)⟩ e ⟨[vỹo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/v%E1%BB%B9o)⟩, pois e o ⟨y⟩ sem til já era usado para representar a aproximante não-nasal (oral): ⟨[rayz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rayz)⟩ e ⟨[fevreyro](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fevreyro)⟩.
- Nos casos Us, a vogal `/u/` ocorre na posição velar com os [lábios arredondados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundedness). Portanto, a aproximante nasal inserida é a velar [labializada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labialization) `/w̃/`: `/ũ.a > ũ.w̃a/`.

Num terceiro estágio, já no português e galego modernos, as consoantes aproximantes inseridas anteriormente sofreram [fortição](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forti%C3%A7%C3%A3o), i.e., perderam a característica de aproximante e transformaram-se em oclusivas:

- Nos casos Is, o `/j̃/` transformou-se na consoante nasal oclusiva que ocorre no mesmo ponto de articulação, o `/ɲ/`: `/ĩ.j̃a > ĩ.ɲa/`.
- Nos casos Us, o `/w̃/` transformou-se na consoante nasal oclusiva que ocorre no mesmo ponto de articulação. O problema é que `/w̃/` é uma [consoante co-articulada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-articulated_consonant), e ocorre em 2 pontos: o ponto labial (devido ao arredondamento dos lábios) e o ponto velar (onde a vogal `/u/` era articulada). Portanto, a consoante nasal oclusiva que substituiu o `/w̃/` poderia ser a labial `/m/` ou a velar `/ŋ/`. E de fato ambas alterações ocorreram: no português moderno ocorreu `/ũ.w̃a > ũ.ma/` (*u**m**a*) e no galego ocorreu `/ũ.w̃a > ũ.ŋa/` (*u**nh**a*).

Em resumo, as transformações, do latino até o português moderno, desde a eliminação da consoante nasal até a criação duma outra consoante nasal foram:

- `/i.na > ĩ.a > ĩ.j̃a > ĩ.ɲa/`. Exemplo: ⟨gallina > galỹa > galinha⟩.
- `/u.na > ũ.a > ũ.w̃a > ũ.ma/`. Exemplo: ⟨una > (h)ũa > uma⟩.

Porém, apesar de o português moderno usar as consoantes oclusivas `/m, ɲ/`, alguns dialetos e algumas línguas parentes do Galego-Português se mantêm nos estágios que precederam a fortização:

- Os dialetos brasileiros [nordestino](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialeto_nordestino) e da [costa norte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialeto_da_costa_norte) pronunciam ⟨-uma, -inha⟩ como `/-ũ(w̃)a, -ĩ(j̃)a/` (i.e., como hiato nasal ou vogais intercaladas por aproximante nasal). Eu, por exemplo, falo *"**ũ**a gal**ĩ**a"* em vez de *"**um**a gal**inh**a"*. Ouça, neste [*Uma pra mim, uma pra tu* do Luís Gonzada (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c95hwnzDpSo&t=1m13s), a pronúncia do artigo "ũa" (aos 1:13).
- O [Mirandês](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_mirandesa) possui como artigo feminino a forma em hiato, porem oral, ⟨[ua](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ua#Mirandese)⟩. Mas alguns dialetos possuem ⟨[ũa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C5%A9a)⟩, conservando a nasalidade.
- A [Fala da Estremadura (Espanha)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xalimego) também possui como artigo feminino ⟨ũa⟩, que é por vezes escrito ⟨[un‑a](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/un-a)⟩, com o hífen como artifício para forçar separação silábica, obrigando o /-n-/ a formar sílaba com o /u/ em vez de com o /a/.

[Neste livro](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/158086/mod_resource/content/1/TEYSSIER_%20HistoriaDaLinguaPortuguesa.pdf) são discutidas a fusão nasal do latim para o galego-português, na página 16; e a alteração desses hiatos do galego-português para o português moderno, na página 26.

Comment: Excelente! Então no galego, "ũ.w̃a > ũ.ŋa/ (unha)", *unha* soa um pouco como *unga?* Eu pergunto-me se isto--o *u* convida /w̃/, que convida /m/ ou /ɲ/--não terá alguma relação com a escolha do *m* para o som nasal em fim de palavra (a tua outra pergunta). O som nasal mais frequente em fim de palavra é capaz de ser o /-ãw̃/. Hoje grafamo-lo *-ão* ou *-am* conforme ela seja tónico ou átono (com meia dúzia de exceções). Mas talvez no passado, nalguns dialetos, talvez a pronuncia se aproximasse algo de /ã(w)m/, convidando a grafar a palavra com -*m*?

Comment: Sim, em galego *"unha"* soa semelhante a *"unga"*; ouça a [pronúncia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gl-unha.ogg). Como cogitas, talvez usamos ⟨-m⟩ para escrever sons finais nasais por causa do reflexo do aproximante nasal português `/w̃  > m/`. Em galego, usa-se, para escrever finais nasais o ⟨-n⟩, que é pronunciado com o `/-ŋ/` de *"unha"*, não com o `/-n/` de *"una*" como no espanhol, conforme especificado [aqui](http://consellodacultura.gal/cdsg/loia/gramatica.php),  assim, *"irmán*" (irmão) pronuncia-se `/iɾ'maŋ/`, provavelmente um reflexo do aproximante nasal galego `/w̃  > ŋ/`.

Comment: Isso é no galego padrão, pois nos dialetos orientais *"irmán"* pronuncia-se `/ir'maw/`, com um ditongo semelhante ao português, exceto que oral em vez de nasal (galego não possui ditongos nasais, e muitos dialetos sequer possuem monotongos nasais), conforme especificado no livro «Dialectoloxía da lingua galega» de Francisco Fernández Rei (tentei encontrá-lo na Internet mas só achei uma cópia pirata), e na seção sobre dialetos da [Wikipedia anglófona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galician_language#Dialects).

Comment: Já estou satisfeito com os teus esclarecimentos :),obrigado. Olha lá, o teu "talvez usamos" foi engano ou falas mesmo assim. Até agora só encontrei *talvez* + indicativo no Machado de Assis. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/subjuntivo-ou-indicativo-depois-de-desde-que-e-talvez).

Comment: Falo assim mesmo, nunca imaginei que soaria errado em Portugal. Uso subjuntivo presente quase que majoritariamente em orações subordinadas. Para suposições em oração independente uso o indicativo presente mesmo. Aliás, por aí também se fala "ũa galĩa" em vez de "uma galinha"? Por aqui fala-se em dialetos rurais e soa bastante informal e inculto, mas a meu ver é a forma etimologicamente mais fiel ao português antigo.

Comment: Não, nunca ouvi "ũa galĩa" por estas bandas. Mas encontro *hũa* em muitas publicações ainda do sXIX. Eu convivi muito com brasileiros, mas fiquei surpreendido quando encontrei o "talvez abuso" no Dom Casmurro do Machado de Assis. Tu és do Nordeste, Ceará, certo?

Comment: Editei a resposta para incluir um exemplo, em música, da pronúncia do artigo "*uma*" sem /m/, tal como o *"ũa"* do galego-português.

Comment: Adicionei a pronúncia de "uma" noutras línguas próximas. Eu achei essa ortografia da Fala que substitui ⟨ũa⟩ por ⟨un-a⟩ bem interessante e bastante útil para nomear arquivos, funções, URL e outras coisas de computador que só aceitem caracteres Ascii. A partir de agora vou usar "man-o", "irman-o", etc. quando programar (em vez de "mão, irmão, etc").

Comment: Acrescentei "(Espanha)" à "Estremadura". Também existe uma Estremadura em Portugal.

Comment: Olha lá, Seninha, tu és rapaz para saber responder a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5750/por-que-raz%C3%A3o-%C3%B4-do-singular-passa-a-%C3%B3-no-plural-em-palavras-como-ovo-jog), não?