# Por que no português utiliza ⟨m⟩ em vez de ⟨n⟩ no final da palavra?

Tags: etimologia, ortografia

**tl;dr:** Porque escrevemos "*ordem*" com  ⟨-m⟩, enquanto o restante escreve "*orden*" com  ⟨-n⟩?

No latim existiam basicamente dois grupos de terminações nasais: as finalizadas em ⟨-m/-n⟩ e as finalizadas em ⟨-nt/-nem⟩.

As terminações do primeiro grupo ⟨-am/-an, -em/en, -um/on⟩ eram realizadas como vogais nasais /-ã, -ẽ, -õ/ no latim vulgar, e acabaram "desnasalizando" no latim vulgar tardio e transformaram-se no português ⟨-a, -e, -o⟩. Eis uma lista de palavras latinas com terminação neste grupo, com suas respectivas pronúncias no latim vulgar e descendentes no português (os nomes estão no acusativo, pois é a forma que herdamos):

```
LATIM    (LAT. VULGAR) > PORTUGUÊS
jam      (/jã/)        > já
servum   (/servõ/)     > servo
possum   (/possõ/)     > posso
sum      (/sõ/)        > sou
clarum   (/clarõ/)     > claro
claram   (/clarã/)     > clara
sortem   (/sortẽ/)     > sorte
parietem (/paretẽ/)    > parede
avem     (/avẽ/)       > ave
nomen    (/nomẽ/)      > nome
regimen  (/regimẽ/)    > regime
manum    (/manõ/)      > mão (originalmente "mano", mas o ⟨n⟩ deletou-se)
```

As terminações do segundo grupo ⟨-ant/-anem, -ent/-enem/-int, -inem, -onem/-unt, -unem⟩ perderam os finais "-t/-em" no latim vulgar tardio, sendo realizadas como /-an, -en, -in, -on, -un/; e transformaram-se no português ⟨-ão, -em, -im, -ão, -um⟩, para oxítonas, e ⟨-am, -em, -em, -am, -am⟩, para não-oxítonas. Eis uma lista de palavras latinas com terminação neste grupo, com suas respectivas pronúncias no latim vulgar e descendentes no português (a maioria são verbos na terceira pessoa do plural, mas os nomes estão no acusativo, pois esta é a forma herdada pelo português):

```
LATIM       (LAT. VULGAR) > PORTUGUÊS
leon(em)    (/leon/)      > leão
can(em)     (/can/)       > cão
stan(t)     (/stan/)      > estão
homin(em)   (/homin/)     > homem
fin(em)     (/fin/)       > fim
commun(em)  (/comun/)     > comum
origin(em)  (/origin/)    > origem
ordin(em)   (/ordin/)     > ordem
fuligin(em) (/fuligin/)   > fuligem
aman(t)     (/aman/)      > amam
amen(t)     (/amen/)      > amem
serven(t)   (/serven/)    > servem
toleren(t)  (/toleren/)   > tolerem
facian(t)   (/fakian/)    > façam
fecissen(t) (/fekisen/)   > fizessem
fecerun(t)  (/fekerun/)   > fizeram
```

Minha dúvida está na nossa ortografia. Enquanto todos as demais línguas românicas usam ⟨-n-⟩ para este último grupo de palavras, o português usa ⟨-m⟩. Eis uma lista de cognatos (só usei essas duas línguas porque são as que conheço, mas as demais seguem o mesmo padrão, exceto pelo Sardenho, que se desprendeu do latim bem antes das mudanças supracitadas ocorrerem):

```
amam:    espanhol "aman",    italiano "amano"
tolerem: espanhol "toleren", italiano "tollerino"
comum:   espanhol "común",   italiano "comune"
fim:     espanhol "fin",     italiano "fine"
ordem:   espanhol "orden",   italiano "ordine"
origem:  espanhol "origen",  italiano "origine"
fuligem: espanhol "hollín",  italiano "fuliggine"
```

Por que a ortografia do português usa o ⟨-m⟩ para palavras do segundo grupo enquanto as demais línguas usam o ⟨-n⟩?

A ortografia do português antigo escrevia essas palavras com ⟨-n⟩ (veja a grafia de "*orden*" no final do [1º parágrafo dessa cantiga](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Cantigas_de_Santa_Maria/CCXLI)). Ou seja, em algum momento do passado preferiu-se adotar a grafia ⟨-m⟩ em vez de ⟨-n⟩, implicando numa etimologia incorreta, já que todas as palavras do latim com ⟨-m⟩ perderam a nasalização (primeiro grupo); e criando uma flexão defectiva, já que essas mesmas palavras vão ao plural com ⟨-ns⟩ (exemplo: origem/origens, só adotamos o padrão ⟨-n⟩ no plural, mas o singular possui a inovação ⟨-m⟩ estranha, que só existe no português).

Comment: Acho que me empolguei na pergunta e acabei me estendendo ao descrever o "background", mas creio que assim ficou mais claro o por quê de eu crer que esse aspecto de nossa ortografia é errado (ou estranho), comparando com as demais línguas românicas.

Comment: Acho que a resposta seria a mesma como se perguntássemos por que para representar o som /ɲ/, o português utiliza *nh*, o galego/asturianu/castelhano *ñ*, catalão/aragonês *ny* (o aragonês no passado usou *ñ*), e italiano/francês *gn*.

Comment: Questão interessante. A minha primeira impressão é que o português evoluiu do latim via oral, não escrita; e quando o quisemos escrever, inventámos uma grafia de acordo com as nossas necessidades, não necessariamente respeitando a grafia do étimo latino. No espanhol tem que ser *orden*, porque o *n* é pronunciado como consoante; mas no português, não existe som consoante no fim de *ordem*, portanto em princípio quer *orden* quer *ordem* serviriam.

Comment: @Jacinto, de fato, "**orden**" manteve a consoante final nas demais línguas, o que os obrigaram a usar o **⟨-n⟩**.  Como esse som consonantal se perdeu no português, não se estranharia se criássemos uma ortografia diferente mas que representasse a mesma coisa. Mas acontece que no português antigo escrevia-se, de fato, com **⟨-n⟩** (veja a grafia de "**orden**" no final do [1º parágrafo dessa cantiga de maldizer](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Cantigas_de_Santa_Maria/CCXLI)). Ou seja, em algum momento do passado adotou-se a grafia **⟨-m⟩** em prol de **⟨-n⟩**.

Comment: @Jacinto. Ainda assim, isso não explicaria o por quê de termos adotado **⟨-m⟩** somente no singular (*ordem*), mas no plural continuarmos usando **⟨-ns⟩** tal como fazem as outras línguas (*ordens*). PS: A cantiga que citei parece não ser de maldizer, mas é tão antiga quanto)

Comment: Seninha, não creio que se possa dizer que a certa altura se passou de -m para -n. Encontra-se logo no sXIII *orden, ordem, ordẽ, ordin, ordim* e *ordĩ*; *homem, homen, homẽ* e *home* (e versões sem h). Não havia uma norma unificada. Vê [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) e [Corpo Informatizado do Português Medieval](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/). Agora, eu não tenho uma resposta cabal; só ideias, relevantes, espero. O plural em -ns parece fazer parte dum padrão: palavras como *Afomso, tamto, quamto* encontram-se, mas são raras; por outro lado palavras como *Coinbra, senpre* >>

Comment: >> são frequentes. Parece ter havido uma preferência forte pelo uso do n para nasalar a vogal quando seguida de outra consoante, mas não em fim de palavra.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, a nossa ortografia decididamente não é etimológica. Por isso escrevemos Filipe e não Philippe, máquina e não machina, tísica e não phtysica.

No caso, as outras línguas românicas não tem como utilizar a letra m, pois elas mantém o som na língua falada. É *amano* e não *amamo* em italiano, seria absurdo escrever de outra forma. Da mesma forma em espanhol, onde, embora não haja vogal depois do "n", a pronúncia da consoante é bem clara.

Em português isso não ocorre; a consoante não é mais pronunciada, e a letra "n" ou "m" no caso serve apenas como índice de nasalização (e ditongação) da vogal anterior. Assim, a distinção que existia no latim, entre palavras terminadas em "n" e "m" (em que essas consoantes efetivamente se pronunciamvam) se perdeu e a pronúncia é a mesma em ambos os casos. Se não queremos decorar listas de palavras que terminavam com "m" versus palavras que terminavam com "n" em latim, temos que usar um único sinal gráfico para indicar a nasalização. Optou-se pelo "m", como poderia ter-se optado pelo "n". E manteve-se o "n" no plural, para obedecer à regra segundo a qual não se usa "m" antes de consoantes, exceto "p" e "b".

(Ainda há exceções, como *dólmen* e *dólman*, por exemplo. Não sei qual a lógica disso, mas são muito poucas palavras, e, a não ser *hífen*, de uso bastante infrequente.)

Answer (score -3):

Em Portugal o N final é normalmente pronunciado, portanto orden ler-se-ia /ˈɔɾ.den/ em vez de /ˈɔɾ.dɐ̃j/.