# Por que algumas palavras terminam em "n" e não "m"?

Tags: etimologia, ortografia, mudanças-históricas

Em geral, palavras no português que terminam com um som nasal se escrevem com "ão" ou "m" no final — fora estrangeirismos, claro, como [design](https://dicionario.priberam.org/design). Essa é uma regra de que [já se tratou aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/4614/2764): em resumo, dado que "m" e "n" no final resultam na mesma pronúncia, por simplicidade se usaria apenas uma letra e a opção foi por "m".

Mas há várias exceções, como "hífen", "sêmen" e "cólon". Por que essas (e [outras](https://www.dicio.com.br/palavras-que-terminam-com-n/)) palavras fogem à regra?

Answer (score 4):

Em português europeu a situação é diferente.
Neste, essas palavras *não têm* terminação anasalada.
Não poderiam ser escritas com -m em vez de -n porque isso mudaria a sua pronúncia.

Talvez a razão para *começarem* a ser escritas assim seja distinta; mas hoje em dia não são uniformizadas para -m por questões fonéticas.
Vê este tradutor automático de texto para IPA:

https://european-portuguese.info/pt/ipa#h%C3%ADfen%20e%20s%C3%A9men%20e%20c%C3%B3lon%20mas%20comprem%20e%20tapem%20e%20tapam%20e%20comam%20e%20abriram%20e%20abrir%C3%A3o

> hífen e sémen e cólon mas comprem e tapem e tapam e comam e abriram e abrirão

> ˈi.fɨn i ˈsɛ.mɨn i ˈkɔ.ɫun mɐʃ ˈkõ.pɾɐ̃j i ˈta.pɐ̃j i ˈta.pɐ̃w i ˈko.mɐ̃w i ɐ.ˈbɾi.ɾɐ̃w i ɐ.bɾi.ˈɾɐ̃w

Repara como as palavras -n soam /n/, e as palavras -m soam /ɐ̃j/ (-em) ou /ɐ̃w/ (-am).

Comment: Interessante, mas essa é uma característica do pt-PT atual - como Jacinto comenta na questão linkada no OP, "Encontra-se logo no sXIII orden, ordem, ordẽ, ordin, ordim e ordĩ; homem, homen, homẽ e home" o que indica que havia diferentes pronúncias (ele fala do século 13, mas isso não deve ter mudado imediatamente depois). Ou seja, explica porque não se alteraria atualmente (ou nos últimos séculos) "hífen" para "hífem" e mantém a cerne da resposta como sendo "porque entraram tardiamente no vocabulário da língua portuguesa". Não?

Comment: Creio que possa ser algo parecido no Brasil. Eu falo "bem" como [bẽŋ], mas não é soa esquisito eu falar [bẽj̃ŋ], contudo, eu falar "hífen" ou "sêmen" com [-ẽj̃ŋ] soa bem errado/esquisito.

Comment: @Schilive Minha impressão é parecida com a tua, mas não idêntica: "sêmen" também soa estranho como 'sêmejn', mas "hífen" como 'ífejn' é mais aceitável.

Comment: É, @stafusa, tem todo o sentido isso que dizes. E esta diferença Portugal-Brasil parece vir sobretudo das vossas vogais abertas e das nossas vogais fechadas; na pronúncia brasileira, os dois sons (-m e /m) também me parecem bem chegados - como escreveste.

Answer (score 2):

Pois são palavras que surgiram no português mais recentemente, provavelmente [após o século 16](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortografia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa#Do_Renascimento_ao_in%C3%ADcio_do_s%C3%A9culo_XX:_ortografia_etimol%C3%B3gica), quando a grafia, antes baseada majoritariamente na fonética, passou a dar mais peso à etimologia das palavras.

Como o Miguel Marques coloca no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-as-palavras-terminadas-em-n/31163):

> A razão para as palavras que o consulente apresenta [hífen, hímen e sêmen] terminarem em n é etimológica. Estas palavras entraram tardiamente na língua portuguesa por via erudita, daí não terem sofrido praticamente alterações. De resto, Cunha e Cintra, na Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo, indicam que «em final absoluta de palavras cultas [ocorre] a articulação ápico-alveolar da consoante n» (p. 47), ou seja, a consoante nasal pronuncia-se da mesma forma como em neve ou nada.