# Quando é que "hũa" deu lugar a "uma"?

Tags: etimologia, ortografia, origem-histórica

A palavra ***uma***, na sua evolução a partir do latim *una*, passou por ***ũa,*** frequentemente grafado ***hũa***, forma que aliás sobrevive nalguns falares do Brasil. Ver a resposta a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/como-%C3%A9-que-una-e-unus-do-latim-deram-em-uma-e-um-no-portugu%C3%AAs) sobre a evolução da palavra. O Camões escrevia *hũa*. Vejam o excerto abaixo da [edição original d’*Os Lusíadas* (1571)](http://purl.pt/1/3/#/314), onde se vê também *algũas* e *nenhũa;* também se vê *lũa,* com til, forma que, creio, resulta do latim *luna,* pelo mesmo processo que *ũa* de *una*.

[image]
[Luís de Camões, *Os Lusíadas,* canto nono, 1571 (BNP).](http://purl.pt/1/3/#/314)

Portanto o que eu quero saber é quando foi que *uma* ou, como também se vê no passado, *huma*, substituíu *ũa* e *hũa*. Se as duas formas *uma* e *ũa*, com ou sem *h*, conviveram durante algum tempo, o que não me espantaria, quando é que surgiu *uma* e *huma*, quando é se tornam dominantes, e quando é que desaparecem *ũa* e *hũa*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Andei pesquisando gramáticas dos séculos 16 ao 19 em busca de comentários sobre a grafia do artigo "*hũa/huma*" e sobre sua realização vocálica `/ũ(w̃).a/` e consonantal `/ũ.ma/`. A partir daqui usarei os termos *"pronúncia vocálica"* e *"pronúncia consonantal"* para referir às respectivas pronúncias possíveis dessa palavra.

Eis abaixo as citações relevantes que encontrei.

Tomei liberdade para transcrever o texto à ortografia e à pontuação atual, exceto que, para as transcrições ortográficas, marcadas entre ⟨chevrões⟩, mantive a grafia do autor; enquanto que substituí as transcrições fonéticas do autor, por transcrições no Alfabeto Fonético Internacional, marcadas entre `/barras/`. Tomei liberdade também de inserir alguns *parênteses*, quando fez-se necessário explicar algo.

---

A primeira citação é «[Orthographia, ou a arte de escrever, e pronunciar com acerto a lingua portugueza. Segunda edição. ¶164—165](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=BCLWmz3ooakC&pg=PA83&ci=29%2C929%2C822%2C368)», pelo trasmontano [Madureira Feijó](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madureira_Feij%C3%B3) em 1739 (primeira edição em 1734).

[image: Primeira citação]

> **§ Como se há de pronunciar a palavra ⟨huma⟩**
>
> **¶164** Entre pessoas sábias e doutas se altercou a dúvida *(sobre)* se esta palavra ⟨huma⟩ se havia de pronunciar ferindo com o ⟨m⟩ o ⟨a⟩, deste modo `/u.ma/`; ou unindo o ⟨m⟩ ao ⟨hu⟩ e separando o ⟨a⟩, deste modo `/ũ(w̃).a/`. E como a dúvida passa-se a teima, fui consultado para a decisão, e respondi que, por uso, se pronunciava do primeiro modo; mas que, pelo rigor da arte, se devia pronunciar do segundo por duas razões: a primeira é porque a palavra ⟨huma⟩ compõe-se de ⟨hum⟩ acrescentando a partícula ⟨a⟩, assim como ⟨boma⟩ *(feminino de "bom", na época pronunciado como hiato nasal-oral `/bõ(w̃).a/`, encontra-se também escrito como ⟨bõa⟩ em textos mais antigos)*, na opinião dos que a pronunciam com ⟨m⟩, compõe-se de ⟨bom⟩, acrescentando a partícula ⟨-a⟩ para o gênero feminino. E se ninguém pronunciaria `/bo.ma/` ferindo com o ⟨m⟩ o ⟨a⟩, também não devemos pronunciar `/u.ma/` ferindo do mesmo modo. O mesmo se vê na palavra ⟨alguma⟩, derivada de ⟨algum⟩, que melhor se pronuncia `/algũ(w̃).a/` do que `/algu.ma/`.
>
> **¶165** A segunda razão, a que não ouvi resposta, é que muitos, ou todos os que doutamente escrevem ⟨hũa⟩ e ⟨algũs⟩ com til por cima do ⟨u⟩, suprindo o m, mas assim é, que o til nunca fere na pronunciação alguma vogal, nem se pode pôr em lugar do ⟨m⟩ nas mais palavras, em que o ⟨m⟩ fere alguma vogal. Logo é certo que nas palavras ⟨huma⟩ e ⟨alguma⟩ o ⟨m⟩ não fere a vogal seguinte, e deve pronunciar-se `/ũ(w̃).a, algũ(w̃).a/`, ou se escrevam com ⟨m⟩ ou com til.

Já por 1739 se discutia a pronúncia do artigo. O autor refere-se à pronúncia consonantal `/u.ma/` como sendo a pronúncia popular *pelo uso*; enquanto que a pronúncia vocálica `/ũ(w̃).a/` é a pronúncia dos "doutos" *pelo rigor da arte*. Ele compara com a pronúncia de "boa" (na época "bõa") que sofria do mesmo problema: um hiato nasal-oral com ambiguidade na grafia e pronúncia, ambiguidade essa que hoje não mais existe, já que `/õ(w̃).a/` deixou de ser um hiato nasal (da mesma forma que "lua" deixou de ser "lũa").

---

A segunda citação é «[Orthographia da Lingua Portugueza ¶290](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=n51HAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA116&ci=141%2C510%2C767%2C277)», pelo tipógrafo português Joaquim José Ventura da Silva em 1834:

[image: Segunda citação]

> **§ Lição III. Do Til e seu uso**
>
> [...]
>
> **¶290.** As palavras ⟨huma, alguma, nenhuma⟩ podem-se escrever ⟨hũa, algũa, nenhũa⟩, porque o ⟨m⟩ não fere a vogal ⟨a⟩, por serem estas palavras compostas de ⟨hum, algum, nenhum⟩ acrescentando-lhes a partícula ⟨-a⟩: donde se segue, que o ⟨m⟩ nestas palavras soa com a vogal antecedente, e não com a subsequente, e por isso é que se podem escrever com til porque este nunca fere a vogal.

Esta citação é mais breve, mas dela pode-se deduzir que em 1834, um ano após a publicação da citação anterior, a pronúncia vocálica ainda existia.

---

A conclusão é que ambas as grafias ⟨hũa⟩ e ⟨huma⟩ coexistiram na língua durante um bom tempo até que a forma arcaica passasse a ser usada por escritores mais conservadores, culminando com seu desuso total.

A medida que eu encontrar novas citações relevantes, editarei esta resposta. Também listarei em anexo os dicionários da época que listavam ambas as formas como possíveis.

Comment: Quando ele diz «que melhor se pronuncia /algũ(w̃).a/ do que /algu.ma/», não me parece que esteja a dizer que a primeira é mais comum, apenas que normativamente é a melhor opção.

Comment: Já agora, na transcrição parece que foste longe demais na supressão das vírgulas. A primeira frase fica agramatical («fica a dúvida se esta palavra...»), pelo menos modernamente, já que o argumento de _dúvida_ tem de estar preposicionado com _sobre_. Parece que ele usa a vírgula para marcar pausas e essa primeira devia ser substituída por dois pontos ou travessão.

Comment: @Artefacto, me soa normal usar a palavra "dúvida" seguida da conjunção "se"+oração, em vez de usar uma preposição (como *"sobre"*) entre elas. Não sei se é uma questão dialetal, mas a frase *"fica a dúvida se esta palavra [...]"* ou a frase *"tenho dúvida se a ajuda virá"* não me são erradas, e é o tipo de construção gramatical que percebo diariamente. Mas, de qualquer forma, coloquei em parêntese a preposição que o autor teria suprimido por [elipse](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elipse_(figura_de_estilo)). Sinta-se livre para reverter minhas outras correções de pontuação que achar necessário.

Comment: Quanto à pronúncia de "alguma", realmente, agora que disseste, o autor estava referindo à pronúncia em hiato como normativa, não como usual. Creio ter interpretado errado quando li a primeira vez.

Comment: Isto é muito interessante: quer dizer então em 1739 /umɐ/ ou /uma/ já era a pronúncia dominante. Mas tens alguma ideia de quando surgiu a grafia *huma* e até quando persistiu *hũa*? Até foi mais a pensar nisso que eu fiz a pergunta. Não dever ter havido muita a gente a comentar a pronúncia. A passagem do autor acerca de *boma* é um pouco confusa. Eu nunca vi escrito *boma* por *boa* (já vi *bõa*).

Comment: As grafias ⟨hũa⟩ e ⟨huma⟩ coexistiram por um certo tempo (inclusive, o autor relata que os "doutos" preferiam a grafia conservadora ⟨hũa⟩ e ⟨algũa⟩, mesmo enquanto a pronúncia popular era /uma/). Ainda não achei livros da época sobre dialectologia que indiquem em quais dialetos houve a mudança de /ũa/ para /uma/; pois creio que essa mudança não ocorreu simultaneamente em todos os falares, tendo inclusive sequer ocorrido nos dialetos brasileiros mais tradicionais. Imagino que nos dialetos mais tradicionais do norte de Portugal tal mudança também não ocorreu (e no Mirandês se fala /ũa/ ou /ua/).

Comment: Quanto à grafia ⟨h-⟩ antes de "hũ/hũu/hum", era apenas um recurso ortográfico que indicava tonicidade, substituindo o uso de acento gráfico. Então "hum, he, ha" equivaliam a escrever "úm, é, á".

Comment: Oha lá, Seninha, tu és capaz de ser rapaz para saberes responder a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5695/pron%C3%BAncia-dos-is-e-us-no-brasil).