# Alguma vez se disse “ua” ou “u’a” em vez de “uma” no Rio Grande do Sul?

Tags: regionalismo, mudanças-históricas

Encontrei este *u’a* em *Saga* do escritor gaúcho Erico Veríssimo (Livraria Globo, 4ª edição, Porto Alegre, 1944). Exemplos (negrito meu):

> ao redor de **u’a** mesa (p. 23)
>
> **U’a** mulher loura de seios fartos (p. 23)
>
> A última coisa que vejo antes de cerrar os olhos é **u’a** mão preta junto da minha (p. 70)

A primeira coisa que pensei foi que fosse gralha. Mas encontrei 27 ocorrências, num livro que onde outras gralhas são raras (um *há* sem acento, um adjetivo qualquer no masculino que deveria estar no feminino, e acho que é tudo).

Por outro lado, *ua* (não sei o que lá faz o apóstrofo; talvez seja para marcar a elisão do m) não seria disparatado. O latim *una* virou *ũa* no português medieval, que no tempo do Camões se escrevia *hũa*, que só depois passou a *uma*  (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/como-%C3%A9-que-una-e-unus-do-latim-deram-em-uma-e-um-no-portugu%C3%AAs) e [esta outra](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4631/quando-%C3%A9-que-h%C5%A9a-deu-lugar-a-uma)). A pronúncia *ũa* ainda ocorre no Ceará. Já o latim *luna* era *lũa* no tempo de Camões ([segunda pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4631/quando-%C3%A9-que-h%C5%A9a-deu-lugar-a-uma)) e passou depois simplesmente a *lua*. Ora não teria sido nada de extraordinário se nalguma comunidade *hũa* tivesse tido uma evolução paralela à de *lũa – lua*, o que daria simplesmente *ua*.

Mas eu nunca tinha visto isto antes, e mesmo na *Saga* *uma* é muito mais frequente que *u’a*. O [Aulete Digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/ua) diz que *ua* é forma antiga de *uma*, mas eu acho que eles se enganaram. Eles abonam *ua* com um verso dos Lusíadas, mas na primeira edição (1572) o que está nesse verso, como em todo o resto da obra, é *hũa* (“Emcima delle hũa nuvem se espessava” canto V, estrofe 20; podem baixar a [primeira edição aqui](http://purl.pt/1), e podem ver também [aqui no Instituto Camões](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/contomes/08/texto.html)).

Portanto o que eu espero é que alguém, especialmente os nosso colegas gaúchos, saibam esclarecer esta questão.

Comment: Sou gaucho e li há muito tempo a Saga do Erico Verissimo (livro obrigatório para o Vestibular em algumas universidades). Mas nunca ouvi uma e um de forma diferente.

Comment: @Peixoto, presumo que na edição que leste, estava "uma"? Deve ser uma edição mais recente, não? A minha é de 1944. Li algures que o Erico Veríssimo considerou a *Saga* o seu pior romance! Se este é o pior, eu fico ansioso por ler outros.

Comment: Eu li no final da década de 90, não lembro qual era a edição. Há várias teorias sobre a Saga, inclusive que Erico Verissímo não conseguiria escrever tudo sozinho e houve outros escritores juntos,,,

Comment: Lembro de já ter lido em algum texto muito antigo, mas nem lembro onde foi.  Quanto a "gralha", vou consultar o Aulete e ver o significado.  Imagino que seja o mesmo que "misprint".

Comment: Tendo vivido no RS dúvido que isso sej algum tipo de referência fonética. Também não acredito que seja alguma obscura regra gramatical mas simplesmente um (intencional) artefato tipográfico, do tempo que páginas de livros e jornais eram impressas apartir de um quebra-cabeças de minúsculas peças de metal

Comment: Oh não! um voto negativo! Por que terá sido?

Answer (score 2):

Não se trata de algum tipo de regionalismo, mas de um artifício para evitar **[cacofonia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacofonia)**.

Note que, nos exemplos dados, a palavra seguinte ao *"u'a"* sempre se inicia com a letra "m": escrever/ler "uma" nesses casos provocaria um som estranho causado pela repetição sequencial do fonema "/m/", fazendo *"uma mão"* soar como *"o mamão"*.

Comment: HWF10, isto é muito interessante. Confirmei que quase todas as 28 ocorrências de *u’a* que anotei precedem uma palavra começada com m (das exceções, duas tem um m próximo, "u’a alma", "u’a imagem, a outra é "u’a criaturinha"). Mas tens de nos dizer mais. Este *u’a* foi uma coisa que só o Érico Veríssimo ou um grupo restrito adotou (justificando a classificação de "artificio")?  Ou reflete alguma pronúncia, talvez antiga e caída em desuso, do Rio Grande do Sul? Não respondas aqui em comentário; edita a resposta com a informação adicional >>

Comment: >> Até porque nós aqui gostamos de respostas fundamentadas. Em que é que baseias a tua resposta? [Este artigo fo Cláudio Moreno](https://sualingua.com.br/2009/04/29/cacofatos/?topo=) diz realmente que alguns "gramatiqueiros" propuseram *u’a mão* em vez de *uma mão* para não poder soar como *mamão*. Mas qual poderia ser o problema com *uma mesa, uma maneira" ou "uma mulher"? Se a mera repetição do m fosse desagradável (a ponto de inventar *u’a*), não haveria palavras como *mamãe, mimo* ou *memória*. Mas +1 desde já pela observação pertinente do m na palavra seguinte.

Comment: Creio que não seja o único caso. Um caso que eu conheço, é em uma música, chamada "Mansão sobre o monte", onde se diz "Terei u'a casa no alto do monte" em vez de "Terei uma casa no alto do monte", a fim de que a letra se encaixe na métrica da música. Você pode ouví-la aqui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqjJhgOvKAw

Comment: Sobre a origem, não sei se existe relação, mas no português medieval as palavras para "um" e "uma", podem ser escritas, respectivamente, como "hũũ" e "hũa" (http://medieval.rb.gov.br/verbete.php?verbete=um%2C+uma&id=82901). Talvez seja alguma reminiscência dessa grafia? Apenas uma hipótese, mas não tenho fundamentos para afirmar isso.

Answer (score 1):

Numa aula de Direito Constitucional I recente, um professor fez referência a essa grafia e fiquei instigado procurando por algum esclarecimento. A forma que ele falou denotou que havia certa diferença de significado entre "uma" e "u'a", mas parece ser apenas diferença de grafia mesmo.

Comment: Davi, obrigado e bem vindos. Será que consegues alguma referência sobre o mesmo?

Answer (score 0):

Usa-se u'a para evitar cacofonia.Cacófato é encontro da sílaba ou letra final com a próxima  palavra que forma um som ( até mesmo palavra obscena ) desarmônico

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado por sua contribuição, mas note que sua postagem contém apenas informações já presentes [noutra resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/7731/2764): nessa situação, é preferível registrar sua concordância votando positivamente naquela resposta ao invés de gerar uma postagem redundante.