# Por que o artigo indefinido se escreve "uns" e não "ums"?

Tags: fonemas, morfologia, morfema

Quero saber por que o artigo indefinido se escreve "u**n**s" e não "u**m**s"?

Olhando para os quatro artigos indefinidos:

- Uma - feminino, singular.
- Um - masculino, singular.
- Umas - feminino, plural.
- U**n**s - masculino, plural.

Vemos que só no masculino plural se escreve com "**n**".

Fazendo a análise morfemática acho este exemplo interessante pela simplicidade - apesar de tratar-se de um morfema gramatical e não lexical. Podiamos considerar o "s" como morfema do plural. Para o contraste de género o morfema "a" para o feminino e o morfema zero Ø para o masculino. Portanto:

- Um-a - feminino, singular.
- Um-Ø - masculino, singular.
- Um-a-s - feminino, plural.
- U**n**-Ø-s - masculino, plural.

A pergunta que fica é se consideramos como base o morfema "um" e alomorfe o "un"? Como se chama ao processo linguístico que leva à mudança de consoante (e que teoricamente cria a alomofre na base derivante)?

Comment: Isto tudo é de cabeça, então, talvez me falhe a memória. bad_coder, acho que escrevemos *uns* por dois motivos: escrevia-se assim há provavelmente mais de um milênio, e porque **hoje** *m* só indica anasalamento no final de palavra, ou antes de *p* e *b* — antigamente, tudo era *n*. No caso de *um*, escrevemos *-m* pela regra que disse. Escrevemos *uma*, com m, por uma coincidência, pois, *uma* antes era /ũa/, que leva a *uma*, imagino pela proximidade de /ũ/ a /m/, Mas acho que já sabias disto.

Comment: /ũ/ que dizes é fonema de "un" não sei se será o mesmo de "ua". Estive a pensar desde que postei e talvez seja flexão nominal em número simples e.g. jovem -> jovens (nesse caso o "m" também troca para "n" com o plural "s"). Mas fica a pergunta como chamamos tecnicamente à mudança na consoante? (Resposta ao teu segundo comentário: Sim acho que o morfema seria o mesmo porque tem o mesmo significado, portanto alomorfes).

Comment: bad_coder, o que me intriga é se é uma mudança de consoante tanto quanto é uma mudança de grafema. Digo, a pronúncia de *un-X* e *um* são a mesma (em Portugal, acho que *un* teria seu n pronunciado), e me parece que a única mudança é a letra. Só por isto, dois morfemas são diferentes?

Comment: @Schilive eu não sei fazer transcrições de fonética, mas sei que em Portugal "um" e "uns" é distinto na nazalisação do **n**, mesmo de disséssemos "ums" a pronúncia do **n** é diferente. **Segunda pergunta:** não; se o morfema expressa a mesma coisa é 1 só morfema, se tem grafemas diferentes por uma diferença na pronúnica/fonética são 2 alomorfes de 1 morfema. Neste caso o morfema é "um" que coincide com o numeral, e "un" seria alomorfe por ser menos frequente considerando todas as flexões nominais e derivações em conjunto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É mera convenção ortográfica. Os m e n de ***um*** e ***uns*** não se realizam como consoantes; simplesmente nasalam o u, resultando na vogal nasal [ũ], a mesma nas duas palavras. Eu sei que isto já gerou desacordo nos comentários acima, mas é o que está de acordo com tudo o que vi sobre fonologia da língua portuguesa.

A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (tomo III, 2ª edição, 2021), diz explicitamente que *um* se pronuncia [ũ] (pp. 2828 e 3243), a mesma vogal que em *ass**un**to* (p. 3255). E no tomo I diz que *de um* e *de uns*, quando não se fazem as contrações *dum, duns*, se pronunciam (em Portugal) [djũ] e [djũꭍ] ([j] como i em *d**i**urno*, [ꭍ] como em ***ch**á*). A Infopédia também indica [ũ] em [*um*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/um), e [ũꭍ] tanto em [*circ**uns**crição*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/circunscri%C3%A7%C3%A3o) como em [*circ**um-es**colar*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/circum-escolar).

Portanto as terminações -*m* do singular e *-ns* do plural são mera convenção ortográfica. Que aliás resultam da regra geral da nossa ortografia que dita que a vogal nasal, quando não é indicada por til (*lã, leões*), é indicada por m em fim de palavra e antes de b e p, e por n antes de qualquer outra consoante (incluindo s, quer este indique plural ou não): *ele tem, vem; tu tens, vens*.

Isto não quer dizer que um ouvido atento e apurado não possa detetar diferenças entre o [ũ] de *um* e o de *uns*. A *Gramática do Português* (p. 3247) diz que na fala normal a coprodução de uma vogal (ou outro som) com sons adjacentes “dá lugar a uma variação significativa relativamente ao que se pode considerar serem as suas características canónicas”. Ou seja, a pronúncia exata do [ũ] em *uns* vai ser afetada pelo s; e em *um*, pelo som inicial da palavra seguinte se a houver.

### Análise morfológica

Isto baseia-se nos capítulos “54 Introdução à morfologia” e “55 Morfologia do nome e do adjetivo” de Maria Antónia Mota (doravante simplesmente Mota) na *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (tomo III, pp. 2787-2930). Em primeiro lugar, note-se que a morfologia se baseia na fonologia e não na ortografia. A exposição do assunto recorre à forma ortográfica da palavra só para facilidade de leitura (pp. 2836-7), com explicações adicionais onde necessário.

Na notação de Mota, depreende-se que o radical de *um* e *uns* é U/N/ (omitem-se as barras, UN, se não houver perigo de confusão), em que /N/ é um “autossegmento fonológico nasal flutuante”, uma “consoante subespecificada” (pp. 2809 e 2855), que para o que nos interessa, quando se liga a uma vogal à esquerda, nasaliza-a, podendo desencadear ditongos (*jov**em***); quando se liga a vogal à direita, realiza-se como [n] (*juve**ni**l*). Mota apresenta apenas uma breve discussão da morfologia de *um* e *uns* (pp. 2827-8):

> O artigo indefinido *um*, que se reduz a uma vogal nasal, sugere a possibilidade de duas análises: um radical com a forma fonológica /uN/ (cf. Nota 23), paralelamente a *atum*

Mota não nos mostra diretamente a decomposição de *um* e *uns*, mas mostra a de *atuns*. Nas pp. 2868-9 fica claro que o radical de *atum* é ATU/N/, o de *jejum* é JEJU/N/, etc., e na p. 2881 mostra-nos o plural de *atuns*, dizendo explicitamente que a formação do plural não acarreta nada de especial nesta classe de palavras:

> A adjunção de -/S/ a uma base que apresenta o segmento nasal /N/ em final absoluto do radical/tema e uma vogal nasal ([ũ], por exemplo), ou o ditongo [ɐ̃j̃] em realização fonética não desencadeia nenhum fenómeno em particular:
> [image]

Explicando: “ATUN” é um radical nominal (RN), onde “N” é o segmento nasal; “―” indica a inexistência de índice temático (IT, corresponde à vogal temática dos verbos); logo, o tema coincide com o radical, dando-nos o singular *atum*; e /S/ é o marcador fonológico do plural, cuja realização depende do dialeto e ambiente fonológico.¹

Portanto não há nada de especial na passagem do singular ao plural. Há é entre o masculino e feminino. Não nos deixemos enganar pela ortografia: em *uma* há realmente a consoante fonética [m], enquanto em *um* há apenas o segmento nasal /N/. Pelo que consegui compreender, uma possibilidade (Mota refere “duas possibilidades de análise”) é admitirmos dois radicais diferentes: U/N/ para o masculino e UM para o feminino. A preferência de Mota vai no entanto para um radical comum U/N/, em que o segmento nasal /N/ em *uma* e *umas* se realiza excecionalmente como [m]. Mais ainda, ela adota para *um* a seguinte abordagem (em alternativa a /uN/ indicada acima, p. 2828):

> *um* tem a forma fonológica /uNu/, sendo a última vogal o índice temático. /N/ nasaliza a vogal precedente (/N/ não se realiza como consoante nasal ― cf. grafia arcaica do português *ũu*, *hũum*, *huum*). Na forma final, há fusão das duas vogais idênticas em [ũ], *um*.

A elegância desta abordagem é que do mesmo radical U/N/ resulta um paradigma completo em género e número (*um, uns, uma, umas*) à semelhança dos adjetivos biformes (e.g. *belo, belos, bela, belas*, do radical BEL). Adotando a notação de Mota ficaria (o índice temático -*o* é fonologicamente /u/, Ø indica marcador nulo do singular, e /N/ nasaliza o /u/ anterior no masculino e realiza-se como [m] no feminino):
[image]

No português medieval não havia nada destas complicações: a representação morfológica seria a mesma, mas o índice temático -*o* do masculino não se fundia com o radical, e o segmento nasal simplesmente nasalava o u anterior quer no masculino quer no feminino (não se realizava como [m]), daí as formas medievais *ũu* e *ũa*, pronunciadas com hiato, [ũ.u] e [ũ.ɐ] (resultante da queda no n fonético do latim). O [m] de *uma* terá surgido como forma de preencher o hiato em [ũ. ɐ] (basicamente os lábios quase fecham para pronunciar [ũ]; se fecharem completamente, ao reabrirem para pronunciar o [ɐ], produzem [mɐ]; vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/como-%C3%A9-que-una-e-unus-do-latim-deram-em-uma-e-um-no-portugu%C3%AAs) que explica isto muito bem, e [estoutra](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4631/quando-%C3%A9-que-h%C5%A9a-deu-lugar-a-uma?noredirect=1&lq=1) sobre quando isso terá acontecido).

---

Nota: ¹ Na pronúncia padrão de Portugal, e em geral de quem chia o s, o /S/ realiza-se como [ꭍ], de ***ch**á*, em *un**s** cordeiros*, como [ʒ], de ***j**á*, em *un**s** borregos*, e como [z] em *un**s** anhos*; para quem não chia o s, a maioria dos brasileiros, realiza-se como [s], de *a**ç**o*, em *un**s** cordeiros* e como [z] em *un**s** borregos* e *un**s** anhos*.

Answer (score 1):

No português existem algumas regras especiais para colocar uma palavra no plural, não é simplesmente adicionar a letra "s" no final de qualquer palavra.

Uma dessas regras especiais diz que quando os substantivos terminam com a letra "m", no plural trocamos o "m" por "ns".

Ex:

1. Viagem - Viagens
2. Comum - Comuns
3. Capim - Capins

Existem outras regras especiais também para os seguintes casos:

- Substantivos que terminam com "al", "el", "ol" ou "ul".
- Substantivos que terminam com "il" caso sejam oxítonos.
- Substantivos que terminam com "il" caso sejam paroxítonos.
- Substantivos que terminam em "ão".
- Substantivos que terminam em "s" ou "x" caso sejam paroxítonos.

Comment: Sim, depois fui ver e é a simples regra de mudança da consoante m para n quando ocorre o plural. Mas fica o problema formal se consideramos "um" e "un" alomorfes ou simplesmente realizaçõe fonéticas diferentes de um mesmo morfema. Uma outra questão, também formal, é que as gramáticas não dizem explicitamente se os artigos admitem flexão em número ou se devemos considera-los estritamente lexemas diferentes? Sei que é uma formalidade, mas estava à procura de uma referência na literatura em que algum autor tomasse posição sobre estas formalidades.

Comment: Só para complicar mais um pouco, na análise mofemática os artigos são considerados gramemas. A pergunta era se consideramos os quatro gramemas como tendo um radical comum em que um único lexema coincide com um dos quatro gramemas, e se podemos considerar isto como resultado de flexão nominal após o normal contraste de género (contraste de género esse que alguns autores consideram flexão, outros não).

Answer (score 1):

Em português e em espanhol, vem M antes de P e B.

E vem N antes de todas as outras consoantes.

M é consoante bilabial e P e B também são consoantes bilabiais.

O motivo é esse.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, podes incluir umas referências para uma gramática ou outra obra que tenha estas regras explícitas sff?