# Este uso de "como" + pretérito imperfeito do conjuntivo está correcto?

Tags: verbos, sintaxe, modo-subjuntivo

Pelo que percebo, o uso correcto deste modo destina-se a acções passadas ou atemporais, em orações subordinadas iniciadas por ***que*** (a acção principal geralmente denota pedido, ordem, sugestão, etc.):

> Foi-nos pedido que *ligássemos* antes.
>   Ordenei que se *calassem*!

ou em orações subordinadas condicionais iniciadas por ***se*** ou ***caso***:

> Se *quisesse*, fazia-o eu!
>   Caso isso se *partisse*, terias que o arranjar.

No entanto, tenho-me deparado, recentemente, na [10ª edição da Editorial Presença de *Crime e Castigo* (com tradução de Nina Guerra e Filipe Guerra)](http://www.presenca.pt/livro/crime-e-castigo/), com frases como as seguintes (ponho um pouco mais de texto, para ter a certeza que o contexto é transmitido, e que não é este, porventura, que justifica o uso do tempo):

> Depois, num pânico louco, precipitou-se para o canto onde o buraco no papel de parede servira de esconderijo às coisas, enfiou a mão e durante alguns minutos apalpou-o minuciosamente, passando por todas as reentrâncias e rugas do papel. Como não ***encontrasse*** nada, levantou-se e começou a recuperar o fôlego. (p. 255)

e

> — Com grande prazer. Ao chegar aqui à cidade, e como ***tivesse*** decidido empreender um... *voyage*, quis tomar algumas providências necessárias. (p. 275)

Ambas me soam mal. No segundo exemplo, talvez falte apenas um ***se***, embora o uso repetido deste tempo verbal nesta tradução me leve a crer que não é esse o caso. No primeiro, parece-me que o pretérito perfeito do indicativo seria mais indicado.

Os tradutores fizeram uso do modo verbal errado, ou falha-me alguma coisa?

Comment: Tive que adicionar um citação dos Ornatos à resposta, lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa construção está correta mas é arcaizante. O que te falta a ti, e a mim, e provavelmente à maioria de nós, é exposição a ela. Mas foi muito comum no passado e mantém-se ainda hoje, ainda que seja rara. Mas se o Machado de Assis, Alencar, Camilo e Júlio Diniz escreviam assim, não podemos dizer que esteja errado. Vejamos o que já dizia há quase um século [Said Ali na *Gramática Histórica da Língua Portuguesa*, 1931](https://archive.org/stream/M.saidAli.grammaticaHistoricaDaLinguaPorugueza/GrammaticaHistoricaDaLinguaPortugueza#page/n415/mode/2up) (2ª parte, p. 127, grafia original):

> O port[uguês] hod[ierno], construindo sentença causal de *como*, prefere o imperfeito do indicativo ao imperfeito do conjuntivo para os actos passados, e serve-se do indicativo se tem de pôr o verbo no presente. Antigamente era mais frequente o emprego do imp. do conj. e em alguns autores occorrem tambem exemplos do presente do conjuntivo:
>
> > *Como* a tarde *fosse* serena e as arvores com gracioso ar *se meneassem*… lhe trouve aa memoria aquelle gracioso tempo (Mor. Palm. 1, 4)—*Como* o gigante *viesse* folgado e *fosse* dos mais forte do mundo… pelejava tam animosamente (ib. 1, 60)—E *como* o amor de Deos *seja* alto e *vença* todas as cousas, fica o bom subdito alto e vencedor obedecendo a hum baixo e vencido (H. Pinto 1, 129)—*Como* amizade *seja* hũa das boas cousas que ha no mundo, e *seja* fundada em virtude e razão natural, e no mesmo Deos, está claro que não ha entre perversos e depravados inimigos da virtude (ib. 2, 289)—*Como* não *achasse* mais que folhas [na fiqueira], amaldiçoou-a (Vieira, Serm. 5, 540).

Os autores citados por Said Ali são [Francisco Moraes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_de_Moraes_Cabral) e [Frei Heitor Pinto](http://www.cm-covilha.pt/simples/?f=2397) do século XVI e o [Padre António Vieria](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%B3nio_Vieira) do século XVII, mas o [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) mostra que a construção era ainda comum na literatura do século XIX e até mesmo do princípio do XX; e ainda se encontra ocasionalmente no final do século XX. Eis alguns exemplos (ênfase minha):

> E, **como soubesse** que a familia real estava em Cintra, conjecturou que os deputados, e particularmente Calisto, deviam estar em Cintra para de lá governarem a Monarchia.
>   [(Camilo de Castelo Branco, *A Queda d’um Anjo*, 1866, p. 209.)](http://purl.pt/139/3/#/212)
>
> Já estou boa. E **como desatasse** o lenço, a mãe disse-lhe timidamente que era melhor atá-lo, mas Capitu respondeu que não era preciso, estava boa.
>   [(Machado de Assis, *Dom Casmurro*, 1899.)](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/download/texto/ua000194.pdf)
>
> Estendeu-me a flauta. ― Toma. E ***como tivesse ficado*** indeciso, disse-me que era para mim [(Alves Redol, *Fanga*, 1943.)](https://www.google.pt/search?q=%22E%20como%20tivesse%20ficado%20indeciso%22&num=50&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF2fHHrsXRAhXFVxoKHd27AD0Q_AUIDCgF&biw=1242&bih=580)
>
> Deu-lhe um riso áspero—àquela moça novidadeira, que, muito satisfeita, virava para o canto da parede e logo depois caía no mais doce dos sonos. **Como estivesse** vestida, Basília saiu sem demora do quarto. [(Dinah Silveira de Queiroz, *A Muralha*, 1954.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=3AwtAAAAIAAJ&q=%22Deu-lhe%20um%20riso%20%C3%A1spero%E2%80%94%C3%A0quela%20mo%C3%A7a%20novidadeira,%20que,%20muito%20satisfeita,%20virava%20para%20o%20canto%20da%20parede%20e%20logo%20depois%20ca%C3%ADa%20no%20mais%20doce%20dos%20sonos.%20Como%20estivesse%20vestida,%20Bas%C3%ADlia%20saiu%20sem%20demora%20do%20quarto%22&dq=%22Deu-lhe%20um%20riso%20%C3%A1spero%E2%80%94%C3%A0quela%20mo%C3%A7a%20novidadeira,%20que,%20muito%20satisfeita,%20virava%20para%20o%20canto%20da%20parede%20e%20logo%20depois%20ca%C3%ADa%20no%20mais%20doce%20dos%20sonos.%20Como%20estivesse%20vestida,%20Bas%C3%ADlia%20saiu%20sem%20demora%20do%20quarto%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPl6nNp8XRAhXHMhoKHeaHBUIQ6AEIHTAA)
>
> Era sudanês e vivia em Cartum, mas, **como não encontrasse** emprego na capital, decidiu partir para o Darfur. [(Paulo Moura, “Esquecimento”, *Público*, 9-12-2007.)](https://www.publico.pt/opiniao/jornal/esquecimento-240799)
>
> O tocador de flauta, ***como tivesse terminado*** o trabalho ajustado, foi-se afastando, fleumático, com o seu estojo debaixo do braço. 
>   (Mário de Carvalho, *Um deus passeando pela brisa da tarde*, 1994.)

---

Atualmente o conjuntivo tem mais alguns outros usos comuns além dos indicados na pergunta:

> Não vais achar nada bem que eu pague a conta em raiva.
>   E **pudesse** eu pagar de outra forma! E **pudesse** eu pagar de outra forma!
>   [(Ornatos Violeta, *Ouvi Dizer*, 1999.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhh_D9e5TaA)
>
> Bateste à porta e ninguém atendeu? Talvez **estivessem** nas traseiras.
>
> Lamento, mas já não há bolo. Olha, **chegasses** mais cedo.
>
> Oh! quem tanto **pudesse** que **fartasse**
>   Este meu duro génio de vinganças (Luís de Camões)
>
> Trabalhava todos os dias, **chovesse** ou **fizesse** sol.

Nestes exemplos, tal como no uso em orações subordinadas exposto na pergunta, o subjuntivo exprime potencialidade, hipótese, incerteza, possibilidade, irrealidade ou indeterminação, e é isso que nós normalmente esperamos. No uso em questão, nas orações causais de *como*―“como desatasse o lenço, a mãe disse-lhe”…―exprime um facto, e é isso que no causa perplexidade por falta de familiaridade. Note-se no entanto que esta associação do conjuntivo ao potencial, incerto, etc. é apenas uma tendência. Veja-se o que diz a *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 583):

> A distinção entre o MODOS INDICATIVO e CONJUNTIVO é complexa. Não existe correspondência entre os dois modos e distinções modais, um vez que a cada MODO se pode associar mais do que uma MODALIDADE.[...] A análise do CONJUNTIVO não tem sido consensual, considerando alguns linguistas que as duas formas surgem apenas por exigência de construção sintática.

E o que se passa é que existe alguma tolerância nestas “exigências de construção sintática”, e as “preferências”, como lhes chama Said Ali, têm variado. Temos também um exemplo oposto: no passado usou-se o indicativo após *talvez* e *desde que*, onde presentemente usamos o conjuntivo: *talvez abuso* versus *talvez abuse*; *desde que não me aborrece* versus *desde que não me aborreça* [(vê esta pergunta)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/subjuntivo-ou-indicativo-depois-de-desde-que-e-talvez). Exemplo similar noutra área: era comum no passado dizer-se *já lhe não parecia* em vez de *já não lhe parecia* [(vê esta pergunta)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4291/pronome-antes-da-nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Comment: Interessante. Então achas que nenhum dos exemplos é hipotético e que o _como_ é causal? (ou pelo menos o primeiro)

Comment: Eh pá, eu não ponho as mãos no fogo. Mas parece-me que nos exemplo quer da pergunta, quer da minha resposta, aquilo é tudo factual.

Comment: @JNat O primeiro exemplo ajudaria ter mais contexto. A minha interpretação foi que o pânico passou porque ele de facto encontrou qq coisa, mas que de seguida agiu como se não tivesse encontrado nada. Mas estando a leitura causal de _como_ disponível, a tua interpretação parece-me mais plausível.

Comment: Os exemplos da pergunta são ambos factuais, sim. Pelo menos o primeiro é mesmo, com toda a certeza: ele não encontrou, de facto, nada.

Comment: @Artefacto Mas encontrei este exemplo do Público em que é conjuntivo com ***se*** omisso: «***Como não bastassem*** já as terríveis tragédias do Médio-Oriente libaneses, curdos, palestinianos, etc para enegrecer as páginas da História Contemporânea, tornou- se necessário reeditar o inferno balcânico» Ou melhor, quer pretérito perfeito, quer ***como se não + conjuntivo*** funcionam, mas o último seria talvez mais esperável.

Comment: Sim, de facto o não ajuda à omissão da conjunção: _não fora o que ele me disse_. Esse é o caso que cubro na minha resposta, cujo alcance agora limitei...

Comment: Isto parece acontecer no espanhol: _hombrre... eso es serio! - murmuró el viejo asustado; y como viese que el otro prolongaba su silencio, tiróle de la lengua, diciendo_

Comment: O uso da flexão -asse- na península ibérica sem valor conjuntival era muito como.  Tenho um livro que estou a editar agora do século XV que o emprega, acho, cada três ou quatro frases.  O exemplo que da @artefacto do castelhano me parece mais bem um erro mais o menos comum, que deveu ser «como viera» (== como había visto), porque mesmo se fosse de tipo «como viese» (== en cuanto viese / hubiese visto), deveu ir em indicativo por acontecer definitivamente antes da acção de tirar (mas como tem «tiróle», não é moderno, assim as regras podem ter sido diferentes, como mencionei)

Comment: @JNat Editei substancialmente a resposta; parte agora, outra parte já há algum tempo.

Comment: Como @Artefacto disse, isto também ocorre em espanhol (e é arcaizante). Também tem o subjuntivo espanhol no antepretérito: "Hubieras llegado antes" = "Tivesses chegado antes" (como condição para ter podido fazer alguma coisa).

Comment: @pablodf76, isso ainda nós dizemos. É basicamente exprimir uma condição sem o *se*. O Artefacto tem um exemplo no imperfeito, "Gostasses tu dela, não terias"... mas podemos também dizer, "tivesses tivesses (tu) chegado antes, ainda terias comido bolo".

Answer (score 2):

Como diz o Jacinto, na primeira frase *como* parece ter um valor causal ou disso próximo; o verbo usar-se-ia geralmente no Indicativo. Mais informação na resposta dele.

O resto da minha resposta cobre cobre uma interepretação hipotética das frases (que poderá ser o caso para o teu segundo exemplo), equivalente a *como se*.

É de facto possível omitir a conjunção, da mesma forma que as duas frases seguintes são equivalentes:

> - Se gostasses dela, não lhe farias isso.
> - Gostasses tu dela, não lhe farias isso.

E da segunda (repara que a inversão é obrigatória), poderíamos omitir ainda o *tu* (com alguma perda de claridade):

> - Gostasses dela, não lhe farias isso.

Portanto, as três frases são também equivalentes:

> - Não ages como [agirias] se gostasses dela.
> - Não ages como [agirias] gostasses tu dela.
> - Não ages como gostasses dela.

Agora, a última frase é de facto bastante incomum em Portugal (*como* + *<pretérito imperfeito do conjuntivo>*) só dá dois resultados relevantes no CETEMPúblico (texto jornalístico), mas quando vamos para o *corpus* TODOS, que contém também textos literários e brasileiros, encontramos muito exemplos:

> - Taunay descreveu-os nos moldes dos antigos fundadores de Roma, **como fossem eles** patres patriae («os pais da nação») ou ditadores romanos (Taunay, 1929, p. 107, 115).
> - Entretanto, o pajem, **como interpretasse** de modo afirmativo o silêncio do sacerdote, continuou: -- Nhanhã Helena é uma santa.
> - O Marquês de Pombal, **como pressentisse** o perigo que podia advir da hegemonia econômica da Inglaterra, inspira-se em Colbert, para a realização do seu plano de fomento econômico.

Dito isto, também há exemplos que não se coadunam com esta interpretação, como esta passagem de Machado de Assis (cf. [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/subjuntivo-ou-indicativo-depois-de-desde-que-e-talvez) e resposta do Jacinto):

> No fim do almoço, **como fumássemos**, deu-me novamente a indicação da casa em Lisboa, o título da folha política em que colabora, e ia confiar-me alguma coisa mais que calou, pareceu-me.