# "Ainda o não merecemos"―pronome átono antes da negação?

Tags: sintaxe, mudanças-históricas

Eu comecei a ler [*Os Maias* (1888; completo)](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/download/texto/bv000083.pdf) de Eça de Queirós há uns dias e já notei mais de uma vez um padrão que nunca tinha visto antes: negações com um pronome de objeto direto colocado antes da palavra *não*. Por exemplo (acho que deve ter mais):

> "Teu pai é uma espécie de santo, ainda o não merecemos…"  [(*Os Maias*.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=DjuaAAAAIAAJ&q=%22teu%20pai%20%C3%A9%20uma%20esp%C3%A9cie%20de%20santo%20ainda%20o%20n%C3%A3o%20merecemos%22&dq=%22teu%20pai%20%C3%A9%20uma%20esp%C3%A9cie%20de%20santo%20ainda%20o%20n%C3%A3o%20merecemos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi90LOPurjSAhUCXBQKHTrOBmUQ6AEIOjAE)
>   "Afonso não ousou beijá-lo, para o não acordar com as barbas ásperas…" [(*Os Maias*.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=CVZfAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Afonso%20n%C3%A3o%20ousou%20beij%C3%A1-lo,%20para%20o%20n%C3%A3o%20acordar%20com%20as%20barbas%20%C3%A1speras%22&dq=%22Afonso%20n%C3%A3o%20ousou%20beij%C3%A1-lo,%20para%20o%20n%C3%A3o%20acordar%20com%20as%20barbas%20%C3%A1speras%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVpcSqvbjSAhVB7RQKHTihB8YQ6AEIIzAB)

Era isso comum ou habitual no português europeu do século XIX? É possível encontrar tal forma hoje em algum dialeto ou registro?

Comment: Ótima pergunta.

Comment: Incluí links, ao livro completo, e diretos às passagens citadas; e inclui um exemplo no título. Se não gostares, sabes onde é o botão do rollback...

Comment: Também posso lincar à página relevante da edição original, mas não dá para destacar a frase, e.g. ["o não merecemos, p. 55, penúltimo parágrafo](http://purl.pt/23/3/res-5011-p/res-5011-p_item3/index.html#/64). Está na grafia original, claro: "Teu pae"... "Affonso não ousou beijal-o"... etc.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas edições. Quanto a grafia, eu usei a da edição Kindle (modernizada).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, esse padrão foi comum no português, europeu e brasileiro, até ao século XIX. Chama-se a isso ***apossínclise***, que é, citando [este artigo do Ciberdúvidas:](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sinclise-apossinclise-e-dissinclise/30086)

> intercalação de uma ou mais palavras entre o verbo e o pronome átono proclítico (ex.: «o que eu lhe não disse» [em vez de: «o que eu não lhe disse»]). Conforme explicado na *Gramática da Língua Portuguesa*, de Mateus *et alii* (2003:866-867), este processo era generalizado no português antigo e clássico, contudo, a partir do século XVII, a interpolação restringe-se à palavra **não** [...]

Mas a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (2013, tomo I, p. 37) observa que interpolações mais variadas continuam a ocorrer em romancistas do século XIX e em falares regionais atuais.  E dá o exemplo “quando lhe eu disse” (em vez de *quando eu lhe disse*), registado no Alto Alentejo no final do século XX.  E ainda hoje eu encontrei “se me ella saisse um lôgro” (em vez de *se ela me saísse*) em [*Cavar em Ruínas* de Camilo Castelo Branco](https://archive.org/details/cavaremruinas00cast/page/18) (p. 19, originalmente publicado em 1866). Mas nada disto se compara a “pois m'eu [tanto] por vós de peidos vazo” (…*me vazo*) nesta [cantiga de escárnio e maldizer](http://www2.fcsh.unl.pt/lit/cantiga_print.asp?cdcant=1415) do século XIII.

Não me recordo de ter encontrado esta apossínclise no português atual. Quando comecei, aqui há uns poucos anos, a ver isso em autores do século XIX, também estranhei (eu tinha lido *Os Maias* na escola há muito tempo, mas já não me lembrava).

Agora, andei a ver no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/x.asp), e mesmo no século XIX é mais comum o pronome depois do *não*. Mas há um padrão interessante. Salvo raras exceções, o pronome só vem antes dos *não* nas circunstâncias que atualmente exigem a próclise (ignorando aqui a negação, que exige, ela mesma, a próclise). Exemplos (negrito meu; indico a data da primeira edição, não a da edição do Google Books):

> Descanse, **que lhe não** tocarei num cabelo! [(Aluísio Azevedo, *A Condessa Vésper*, 1882.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=SYhcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT237&dq=%22Descanse,%20que%20lhe%20n%C3%A3o%20tocarei%20num%20cabelo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhkvf616vSAhXIyRQKHTNgDc4Q6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Descanse%2C%20que%20lhe%20n%C3%A3o%20tocarei%20num%20cabelo%22&f=false)
>
> A medicina,—**por que lhe não** manda ensinar medicina?
>   [(Machado de Assis, *Dom Casmurro*, 1899.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9x-9BwAAQBAJ&pg=PT76&dq=%22A%20medicina,%20por%20que%20lhe%20n%C3%A3o%20manda%20ensinar%20medicina%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwici9u52avSAhWCthQKHRx5AM4Q6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=%22A%20medicina%2C%20por%20que%20lhe%20n%C3%A3o%20manda%20ensinar%20medicina%22&f=false)
>
> O vinho, o famoso vinhito do Filipe do Ver-o-peso, **já lhe não** parecia o mesmo.
>   [(Inglês de Sousa, *O Missionário*, 1891.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=t-0gDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT61&dq=%22Filipe%20do%20Ver-o-peso,%20j%C3%A1%20lhe%20n%C3%A3o%20parecia%20o%20mesmo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBxO7A2qvSAhXHOBQKHZSoC84Q6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Filipe%20do%20Ver-o-peso%2C%20j%C3%A1%20lhe%20n%C3%A3o%20parecia%20o%20mesmo%22&f=false)
>
> [...] às vezes, de quando em quando, **se te não** custasse
>   [(Júlio Dinis, *Uma Família Inglesa*, 1868.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=PHruAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%C3%A0s%20vezes,%20de%20quando%20em%20quando,%20se%20te%20n%C3%A3o%20custasse%22&dq=%22%C3%A0s%20vezes,%20de%20quando%20em%20quando,%20se%20te%20n%C3%A3o%20custasse%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivq6br26vSAhVEwxQKHYL4Ac4Q6AEIJzAC)
>
> Não percebeste que era mentira, que eu dizia isso **para te não** molestar?
>   [(Machado de Assis, *Memórias Póstumas de Brás Cubas*, 1881.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=8bdcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT50&dq=%22N%C3%A3o%20percebeste%20que%20era%20mentira,%20que%20eu%20dizia%20isso%20para%20te%20n%C3%A3o%20molestar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi384al3avSAhUF1hQKHTTRB84Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22N%C3%A3o%20percebeste%20que%20era%20mentira%2C%20que%20eu%20dizia%20isso%20para%20te%20n%C3%A3o%20molestar%22&f=false)
>
> **Como te não** lembraste dele, Ângelo? [(Júlio Dinis, *As Pupilas do Senhor Reitor*, 1867.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=6EIRAQAAMAAJ&q=%22Como%20te%20n%C3%A3o%20lembraste%20dele,%20%C3%82ngelo%22&dq=%22Como%20te%20n%C3%A3o%20lembraste%20dele,%20%C3%82ngelo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibx7OW3qvSAhUBMBQKHe5WA88Q6AEIIjAB)
>
> A caridade **só me não** humilha quando parte do coração e não do dever.
>   [(Camilo Castelo Branco, *Amor de Perdição*, 1862.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=w1cYCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT195&dq=%22A%20caridade%20s%C3%B3%20me%20n%C3%A3o%20humilha%20quando%20parte%20do%20cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20e%20n%C3%A3o%20do%20dever%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj537yw7KvSAhWKshQKHaWzDs4Q6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22A%20caridade%20s%C3%B3%20me%20n%C3%A3o%20humilha%20quando%20parte%20do%20cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20e%20n%C3%A3o%20do%20dever%22&f=false)
>
> [...] e faça favor **de me não** quebrar mais a cabeça;
>    [(Inácio Maria Feijó, *Camões no Rossio*, 1810.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=57lXAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA97&dq=%22e%20fa%C3%A7a%20favor%20de%20me%20n%C3%A3o%20quebrar%20mais%20a%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjokozH6qvSAhVDcRQKHaKEDM4Q6AEINzAE#v=onepage&q=%22e%20fa%C3%A7a%20favor%20de%20me%20n%C3%A3o%20quebrar%20mais%20a%20cabe%C3%A7a%22&f=false)

Reparem que nestes exemplos, mesmo tirando o *não*, a outra palavrinha a negrito obriga o pronome a ficar antes do verbo. Salvo raras exceções, na ausência destas palavrinhas [(vejam aqui uma lista mais longa, mas não completa, destas palavrinhas)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/294/coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-pronominal/4283#4283), o pronome fica sempre depois do *não*. No entanto, também encontramos o pronome depois do *não* mesmo na presença destas palavrinhas, e pela pena dos mesmos autores. Portanto parece que estas palavrinhas simplesmente permitiam a colocação do pronome antes ou depois do não, enquanto que sem elas teria de ser sempre depois. Esta colocação do pronome antes de *não* parece ter persistido por mais tempo em Portugal, e ainda se encontram exemplos infrequentes no final do século XX.

Comment: Obrigado por tanta e tão completa informação! Eu também não tinha claro o negócio das "palavrinhas" (e ainda bem que já existia uma pergunta e uma resposta acerca delas).

Comment: Excelente resposta.

Comment: Jacinto,  tu usarias o acento grave em "até a hora de irmos embora"?  Caso negativo, porque "ao" em "até ao século"?

Comment: @Centaurus Claro, "até à hora de irmos embora", "até ao minuto", mas, incoerentemente, "até sábado". É como se escreve por estas bandas;  e como se fala (***a*** é fechado, ***à*** é aberto). Também notei quanto vi que no Brasil é "até a hora" e "até o minuto". Mais uma daquelas diferençazinhas.

Comment: @Jacinto  Mas não ficam duas preposições seguidas?

Comment: @Centaurus Sim. Mas preservar a sintonia com a língua falada é mais importante para eles do que evitar a dupla preposição. Seria "gramaticalmente incorreto" no Brasil, se está se perguntando. Mas não seria algo inédito, a língua portuguesa tem um certo histórico de complacência com a dupla preposição (vide _para com_).

Comment: @RamonMelo   Valeu.

Comment: @Centaurus Pois ficam duas preposições seguidas.

Comment: @Ramon, A dupla preposição é óbvia quer na escrita, quer na fala. É óbvia em "até ao último minuto"; e para nós é óbvia também em "até à vista", porque este ***à*** é aberto, enquanto ***a*** é fechado. "**Até à vista**" aqui soa diferente de "**até a vista** doeu" (= "mesmo a vista doeu). Eu falo assim desde criancinha; nunca me preocupei com a lógica, ou falta dela, da dupla preposição.

Comment: @Jacinto Complicado. Você certamente aprendeu a língua oral antes da escrita, e certamente antes da norma escrita. Existe uma naturalização do regionalismo que provoca um certo _confirmation bias_, como você parece reconhecê-la em "nunca me preocupei com a lógica, ou falta dela", e, cometendo o pecado da generalização, seus conterrâneos parecem seguir seus passos. Mas, para nós que cá estamos, fica o estranhamento diante da falta de lógica. Se não vem da língua falada (já que a escrita não possui pronúncia), qual a razão para esta construção ter surgido e se popularizado?

Comment: Disclaimer: Longe de mim exaltar a lógica dos dialetos brasileiros. Temos - e sinto um certo orgulho disto - uma quantidade assombrosa de construções ilógicas, a maioria delas com alguma _justificativa_ (por mais meia-boca que seja).

Comment: @Ramon, Pois, é uma boa pergunta. Mas já vem, por escrito, pelo menos do sXIX, e não era só aqui: "Sim, leitora castíssima, como diria o meu finado José Dias, podeis ler o capítulo **até ao fim**, sem susto nem vexame" [Machado de Assis, *D. Casmurro*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=LszFPnNUVhMC&pg=PA117&dq=%22ler+o+Cap%C3%ADtulo+at%C3%A9+ao+fim%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis6e6fxbDSAhVBthQKHaOvCEoQ6AEIcTAL#v=onepage&q=%22ler%20o%20Cap%C3%ADtulo%20at%C3%A9%20ao%20fim%22&f=false).

Comment: @Ramon, revisitei esta pergunta antiga, e creio que a tua pergunta acima, acerca da origem da dupla preposição *até a*, agora já tem resposta [aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5315/%c3%89-correto-usarmos-duas-preposi%c3%a7%c3%b5es-seguidas/8054#8054).