# Pronoun syntax w/ certain verbs (EU Portuguese)

Tags: português-europeu, pronomes

I am aware of the [rules](https://www.learn-portuguese-with-rafa.com/european-portuguese-pronouns.html) of pronoun positioning in Portuguese.

When are pronoun affects a verb (and there is nothing to make it preceed the verb), it will come after the verb it's affecting, eg:

> Vou usá-**lo** hoje.
>
> Vou falar-**lhe** hoje.

However, I have seen many examples of the following:

> Não **o** vou usar hoje.
>
> Não **lhe** vou falar hoje.

Why is it that, when in the negative, the pronoun now chooses to precede the initial verbs (in this case, *poder*, and *ir*, rather than the verbs they actually affect (*usar*, and *falar*)?

Comment: What do you mean "why"? Are you asking for some unified gramatical model of clictic placement in European Portuguese? Because there are many...

Comment: 3 words: [*Próclise, Ênclise e Mesôclise*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pronominal), próclise is more common on pt-BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some verbs (mainly auxiliary and semiauxiliary verbs), when followed by a simple infinitive clause, can see the clitic "climb" outside the infinitive clause. That's the case with *poder* and *ir*. You could also say:

> Vou-**o** usar hoje.
>   Vou-**lhe** falar hoje.

In the negative, proclisis must be used, so we get:

> Não **o** vou usar hoje.

Now, it is true that clitic climbing is more common with proclisis. In particular, with *poder*, the enclisis is arguably marginal, depending on who you ask:

> Não **te** posso ver ao fim da tarde.
>   (?) Posso-**te** ver ao fim da tarde.

Another question is why a proclisis to the infinitive verb is not possible, as it is in Brazilian Portuguese:

> *Não vou **o** usar hoje.

Verbs that take a preposition (like *por* or *de*, but not *a*), can have proclisis to the infinitive verb and admit clitic climbing. But the presence of a context forcing proclisis in the main clause doesn't seem to affect the position of the clitic in the infinitive clause:

> Começou-**lhe** por dizer que não gostava dele.
>   Começou por **lhe** dizer que não gostava dele.
>   Começou por dizer-**lhe** que não gostava dele.
>   Não **lhe** começou por dizer que não gostava dele.
>   Não começou por **lhe** dizer que não gostava dele.
>   Não começou por dizer-**lhe** que não gostava dele.
>
> Nem assim **o** deixaram de fazer/deixaram de **o** fazer/deixaram de fazê-**lo**.

Comment: Must pronouns be raised with atratores (absent prepositions) or is it optional? While *não vou-o usar* sounds bad to me, *não vou usá-lo* or even *não vou poder usá-lo* don't, but I also readily admit they may sound okay to me from influence of other languages. How do they sound to you?

Comment: @guifa, they sound to me just as they sound to you: you don't say *não vou-o usar*, but can say any of the other two.

Comment: @Jacinto perhaps Artefacto might want to generalize the answer then to handle infinitives that aren't preceded by prepositions as well (since the same applies: attach to the infinitive, but preceded the conjugated verb). Also crazier but possible (albeit these days virtually only in writing): *que lhe não começou por dizer*

Comment: @guifa, we have [this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4291/ainda-o-n%C3%A3o-merecemos-pronome-%C3%A1tono-antes-da-nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o) about *ainda o não merecemos*; I'm not sure I've seen that syntax with auxiliary verbs, but can't see why one shouldn't do it.

Comment: @guifa I'm not sure what you mean. The behavior is not the same depending on whether the preposition is there or not (and not all verbs that take a preposition behave the same way; for instance, all verbs that take _a_ do **not** admit a clictic between _a_ and the infinitive verb: *_estou a lhe dizer_). As for interpolation, be it with _não_ or _lá_ / _ali_ / etc., I don't see how it's directly relevant to the question of clictic placement (it can at most gives clues about the underlying structure of the sentences).

Answer (score -1):

As an european portuguese native, it is simple. When the sentence is in the negative form, the pronoun order is simply switched out (in most cases Look at [this article referred by jean](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pronominal) ). In older european portuguese uses could be different. eg.

`Lhe quero muito bem.` - a few centuries ago;
`Quero-lhe muito bem` - currently.

You'll gain the skill by practising reading and hearing natives speak.

Comment: YT Fan, welcome to the PortugueseLanguage site. It appears to me the question is a little different: why we say "não lhe vou falar" rather than "não vou lhe falar"?

Comment: it's não lhe vou falar. Some natives lack education and say não vou falar-lhe but that is completely wrong.