# Modo de verbos em cláusulas com o verbo imaginar no afirmativo

Tags: modo-subjuntivo

Qual é (ou seria) a explicação do facto de ser usado tão comummente o conjuntivo com o verbo *imaginar* no afirmativo?

É plenamente óbvia a razão quando vai em negativo:

> Não imagino que … [conjuntivo]

Como não o imagino, é como pô-lo em dúvida. Mas ultimamente notei que no português, mesmo no caso afirmativo, se emprega muito o conjuntivo, coisa que acho esquisita —nas línguas irmãs que falo, ele seria usado só sob certos contextos muito específicos, sendo o normal o indicativo—.  Imaginar algo é como achá-lo, ou crê-lo, e todos estes verbos usariam o indicativo em frases como «Creio/acho que … »

Imagino que (ha!) a primeira pergunta a fazer seria se se considera correto ou errado o uso do subjuntivo numa frase como «imagino que seja», e só caso seja, perguntar quais as regras que rejam/ditem o seu uso frente ao indicativo (diferenças regionais, de registo, etc).

Comment: A pergunta continua um pouco confusa, mas eu acho que não a consigo melhorar.

Comment: @ANeves só por ter um *que* não implica o conjuntivo. Não dizemos "vejo que seja..." ou "creio que seja", senão "vejo que é" e "creem que é" (porque estamos a falar da realidade do que crê/vê). Mas ao usar essos verbos em negativo, sai o conjuntivo: "não creem que seja", "não vejo que seja", etc.

Comment: A tua pergunta ficava mais clara se pusesses, explicitamente, um desses pares de frases. Completas, e não com elipses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, pelo menos em Portugal, verbos como *imaginar, acreditar, crer, achar, julgar* e *pensar* (no sentido ‘achar’) podem selecionar quer o indicativo quer o conjuntivo (*subjuntivo* é o termo preferido no Brasil). Basicamente a diferença é que, por exemplo, *penso que ele está em casa* indica maior convicção de ele estar em casa do que *penso que ele esteja em casa*.

Esta distinção vem descrita na *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013). Esta é uma gramática descritiva do português europeu; nunca me apercebi que haja neste ponto diferença no português do Brasil, mas não ponho as mãos no fogo. Citando a *Gramática* (tomo I, p. 679-80):

> Há ainda um grupo de predicados epistémicos que admitem o indicativo ou o conjuntivo. É o caso de verbos como *acreditar, admitir, imaginar*, entre outros, e de nomes como *hipótese, ideia,* ou *suspeita*:
>
> (21) a. Acredito que *existiu* vida em Marte.
> b. Acredito que *tenha existido* vida em Marte.
>
> […]
>
> Nesses casos, a seleção do modo conjuntivo ou do modo indicativo é acompanhada por uma diferença de interpretação. A frase (21a), com indicativo, indica um valor forte de crença, enquanto (21b), com conjuntivo, indica um grau fraco de crença. Assim, (21a) tem um significado semelhante a (23a) e o significado de (21b) aproxima-se do de (23b) […]
>
> (23) a. Estou convencido de que *existiu* vida em Marte.
> b. Não excluo a possibilidade de *ter existido* vida em Marte.

A *Gramática* volta a explicar a mesma distinção no capítulo sobre subordinação finita (tomo II, p. 1843).

Estes verbos quando negados normalmente selecionam o conjuntivo (*não acredito que ele esteja em casa*), mas podem também selecionar o indicativo. Voltando à *Gramática* (tomo II, p. 1844):

> (92) a. O Paulo não acredita que o filho *ganhou* a lotaria.
> b. O Paulo não acredita que o filho *tenha* ganho a lotaria.
>
> O que distingue (92a) de (92b) é grau de certeza do *locutor* (e não do sujeito da oração subordinante) na veracidade da oração completiva. Quando é usado o modo indicativo, existe a inferência que o locutor acredita (ou sabe) que a proposição complemento é verdadeira.

Quanto à lógica deste uso, a *Gramática* (tomo I, p. 680) oferece o seguinte esquema geral:

> Posto isto, verifica-se que os predicados epistémicos podem estar associados a diferentes graus de crença, formando uma escala. Os que expressam valor forte de crença selecionam o indicativo [*eu sei que ele está em casa*], os que estão associados a um valor fraco selecionam o conjuntivo [*duvido que ele esteja em casa*] e os que estão associados a valores intermédios admitem o indicativo ou o conjuntivo, dependendo a seleção de um ou outro modo do grau de crença veiculado em cada frase.

A *Gramática* inclui o verbo *imaginar* neste grupo de verbos associados a valores intermédios, mas eu pessoalmente, provavelmente influenciado pelo que ouço à minha volta, tendo a usar *imaginar* para exprimir valores fracos de crença, e prefiro *imaginar* com o conjuntivo: *imagino que ele esteja em casa*; quando o meu grau de convicção aumenta eu mudo para *creio que* ou *penso que*. Uso o indicativo é em frases negativas como:

> Ela não imagina sequer que o marido a engana.

Como explica a gramática, eu aqui indico que estou convicto que o marido a engana. Se eu ouvisse, *ela não imagina que o marido a engane*, eu entenderia que o locutor não se compromete com a veracidade de *o marido engana-a*.

---

Não é surpreendente que haja nas preferências entre indicativo e conjuntivo diferenças entre o português e as línguas irmãs, pois até as há entre o português atual e o português do passado. Atualmente dizemos *talvez abuse da tua paciência*, mas há pouco mais de um século Machado de Assis escrevia, possivlemente já com um certo sabor arcaizante, “talvez abuso” [(vê esta pergunta)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/subjuntivo-ou-indicativo-depois-de-desde-que-e-talvez). E atualmente correntemente dizemos, *como estava cansado, sentou-se*; no passado era muito mais comum dizer-se *como estivesse cansado, sentou-se*; embora ainda se encontre esta construção com o conjuntivo ocasionalmente na literatura e imprensa recentes em Portugal, ela é tão rara ao ponto de causar estranheza [(vê esta pergunta)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3136/este-uso-de-como-pret%C3%A9rito-imperfeito-do-conjuntivo-est%C3%A1-correcto?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @ANeves, então e não sabes corrigir tu. Para que é que és moderador afinal? Só para receber o cheque ao fim do mês?!

Comment: Não arrebites muito cabelo, olha que os acidentes acontecem.... :-p

Comment: Não gosto de corrigir merdices assim pequenas, acho ranhoso que ficasse "editado por X" por causa de uma niquice.

Comment: @ANeves, editavas mais umas coisas. Não sabes alinhar o "a." e o "b." dos exemplos da gramática, por exemplo?