Uso do verbo "ter" de forma correta
Deparei-me com uma frase escrita em um e-mail (grifo meu):

Isso presume que, para as notas de entrada, termos que contar com o time fiscal para a cobertura dos itens.

Isso soou-me errado. Imagino que o correto seria teríamos ou teremos, porém a pessoa que escreveu a frase jura, de pé junto, que está correta e que "simplesmente existem formas diferentes de escrever".
Existe, mesmo, a possibilidade do uso de termos nesse caso?

Será que a resposta está aqui? https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5598/modo-de-verbos-em-cl%c3%a1usulas-com-o-verbo-imaginar-no-afirmativo

Sem me amparar em fontes - e, portanto, como comentário, não resposta - eu diria que está errado, que o "termos" até pode ser usado, mas então, sem o "que" antecedendo.

Não há nenhuma razão de usar o futuro do subjuntivo. Acho que sim, tá errado.

Está errada a frase. Primeiramente o verbo "ter" de obrigação pela norma culta requer a preposição "de", não a conjunção "que", tal qual o verbo "haver" de obrigação.
Como mencionado por um comentário, o uso da forma "termos", requereria a elisão do "que" após "presume", mas aí "termos" seria não futuro subjuntivo mas indicativo pessoal.
Com a inclusão do "que", as formas "tenhamos de", "teremos de", e "teríamos de" são todas possíveis de acordo com o significado pretenso.

Isso presume, para as notas de entrada, termos de contar com o time fiscal para a cobertura dos itens.

A distinção entre "tenhamos de" e "teremos de" é explicada nesta resposta, mas ambos seguem a fórmula de que X presume que L será o caso; pela semântica do verbo "presumir", L é uma premissa de X.
"Teríamos de" ade mais valor hipotético, na fórmula de que X presume que L seria o caso (dada uma condição adicional V). Exemplos:

A previsão do tempo presume que uma frente fria não virá.


A minha aposta presume que mais nenhum jogador seja expulso.


O orçamento presume que não teríamos um desconto (condição V: se mais pessoas vierem).

Em suma, a frase seria "Isso presume que, para as notas de entrada, tenhamos de" ou "Isso presume que, para as notas de entrada, teremos de", dependendo da semântica preferida.
